# How to plot time of user accounts created in twitter by year?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, plotly, tweets

I have a csv file containing the tweets, user name and the time the user account was created as "created_at", but how should i plot it in python? I want to show number of users vs the year account was created. Is it possible? I am using Jupyter notebook, and as i am new to it any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- your question is quite abstract
- have simulated data that you state that you have in your CSV *created_at*
- using **pandas** aggregate this to number of rows per year
- using **plotly** generate a bar figure

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# simulate CSV
df_tweet = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "created_at": np.random.choice(
            pd.date_range("1-jan-2010", periods=140, freq="MS"), 100
        )
    }
)

# count by year and plot
px.bar(
    df_tweet.groupby(df_tweet["created_at"].dt.year)
    .agg(count=("created_at", "size"))
    .reset_index(),
    x="created_at",
    y="count",
)
```

[image]